# I have a div element on my page that I wish to show/hide based on a session value in my code-behind without runat="server" . How can I do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `div` element on my page that I wish to show/hide based on a session value in my code-behind without `runat="server"` because I use div in JavaScript , how I can do that?

```
function change(rbl, div) {

        //Get the selected value from radiobuttonlist 
        var selectedvalue = $("#" + rbl.id + " input:radio:checked").val();

        if (selectedvalue == "0") {
            //if so then show the controls
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";
        }

        else if (selectedvalue == "1") {
            //if not then hide the controls
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";

        }
        else if (selectedvalue == "2") {
            //if not then hide the controls
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide your example based on these rules : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function ShowHideDiv()
{
   var sessionValue = '<%= Session["MySessionValue"].ToString() %>';

   if(sessionaValue)
   {
      //hide or show div here
   }
}
```

Comment: if i write hide div give me wrong " the name 'DIV' does not exist in the current context " because i don't give the DIV runat="server"

Comment: @MeshariAljbeel Do you want to check the session value in js code or in code behind? If it's code behind then you will have to add `runat="server"`

Comment: no my problem is the Div if i add runat="server" the js not working

Comment: Can you post your js code please and the markup code too

Comment: On your div make sure you have `ClientIDMode="Static"`